# Setting seed, sample kind argument throws warning

Tags: r

I have to set a seed so i did write:

```
set.seed(2, sample.kind = "Rounding")
```

Used sample.kind argument because I have latest R version (4.0.3).
But the console throws:

```
Warning message:
In set.seed(2, sample.kind = "Rounding") :
  non-uniform 'Rounding' sampler used
```

I used this argument quit often in the past and it worked well.

As I see my calculations give the same output for both (with and without sample.kind). Then what is the point of using the additional argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `?set.seed`

> sample.kind can be "Rounding" or "Rejection", or partial matches to these. The former was the default in versions prior to 3.6.0: it made sample noticeably non-uniform on large populations, and should only be used for reproduction of old results. See PR#17494 for a discussion.

This is the bug report https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17494

So it is suggested to not use this kind now hence the warning.